# Blank map with zoom controls on using Google Map's API V2 Fragment Map:

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am tring to implement google maps using the new google maps api v2 and for some reason i don't see a map.

I think that the problem is those two lines of error when i run it on the emulator:

```
 E/ActivityThread( 1373): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
 E/ActivityThread( 1373): Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf
.gservices
```

when i run the application on the device the following error is produced:

```
Could not find class 'maps.j.k', referenced from method map.y.ae.a
```

My problem looks the same as in this link: http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/google-maps-android-api-v2-with-blank.html

There it's says that the problem may be my key so i went and reproduced it using the following tutorial:  http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html. but this still didn't helped me.

the support files are of course add to the project as well as the Google play services lib.
I see the same result on the emulator (after adding manually the two file that allow using the google map v2 on the emulator) as well as on the motorola Defy running android 2.2.

Maybe I am using the wrong debug.keystore? I am using the one in my User.android folder.If so then how do i find the right file?

EDIT: My eclipse says that my debug key is in the default folder. So i renamed the debug.keystore file and ran the Eclipse to recreate it all over again. That resulted in producing a new SHA1 key. I used it to create a new Google Maps API v2 key but the result is still the same. I'm still unable to see the map.

EDIT2: Stupid me, I chose Google Map API V2 instead of Google Maps Android API V2.
       This question can be closed. Thanks.

Here are all the code files:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraBearing="112.5"
    map:cameraTargetLat="-33.796923"
    map:cameraTargetLng="150.922433"
    map:cameraTilt="30"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiCompass="false"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="false"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Map Fragmentactivity class:

```
package com.eadesign.skygiraffefinalv2;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Map extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
{
private GoogleMap map;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()) == 0)
        {
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        //  map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        }
}}
```

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.eadesign.skygiraffefinalv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<permission android:name="com.eadesign.skygiraffefinalv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.eadesign.skygiraffefinalv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/sgicon90"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">       


    <activity
        android:name=".Map"
        android:label="@string/app_name"> 
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>                 
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My key"/>            
</application>
```

log from logcat:

```
ent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.eadesign.skygiraffefinalv2/.Map u=
0} from pid 1362
W/WindowManager(  148): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21010
D/AndroidRuntime( 1362): Shutting down VM
I/ActivityManager(  148): Start proc com.eadesign.skygiraffefinalv2 for activity
com.eadesign.skygiraffefinalv2/.Map: pid=1373 uid=10046 gids={3003, 1015, 1028}
D/dalvikvm( 1373): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
D/dalvikvm( 1362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 77% free 483K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms,
total 13ms
D/jdwp    ( 1362): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
D/dalvikvm( 1362): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
E/jdwp    ( 1373): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
D/dalvikvm( 1373): Debugger has detached; object registry had 2 entries
E/Trace   ( 1373): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
D/dalvikvm( 1373): GC_CONCURRENT freed 204K, 3% free 8264K/8519K, paused 89ms+6m
s, total 161ms
D/dalvikvm( 1373): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
E/ActivityThread( 1373): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
E/ActivityThread( 1373): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
D/dalvikvm( 1373): GC_CONCURRENT freed 312K, 5% free 8471K/8839K, paused 82ms+10
5ms, total 268ms
E/ActivityThread( 1373): Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf
.gservices
E/ActivityThread( 1373): Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf
.gservices
D/dalvikvm( 1373): GC_CONCURRENT freed 227K, 4% free 8797K/9095K, paused 91ms+11
0ms, total 300ms
D/libEGL  ( 1373): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software r
enderer.
I/Choreographer( 1373): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
h work on its main thread.
D/gralloc_goldfish( 1373): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
D/libEGL  ( 1373): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/ActivityManager(  148): Displayed com.eadesign.skygiraffefinalv2/.Map: +3s545ms
I/Choreographer( 1373): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
 h work on its main thread.
```

Comment: So on both your device and the emulator you're getting the same error ? Typically this error will be shown on an emulator since you're not supposed to be able to run the newest version of the Google Play Services (of course work around do exist).

Comment: actually as i wrote i did commit the work around so i could run the map on the emulator but when i run it on the device i see that another error is produced: 

Could not find class 'maps.j.k', referenced from method map.y.ae.a

Comment: It's hard to tell anything from this error message, sadly it seems to be obfuscated.

Comment: its seems to be "obfuscated"? what that's mean?

Comment: Generally Android applications and libraries are obfuscated when they're getting compiled. The class names of the applications are replaced by gibberish, generally letters. So this maps.j.k, could be any package/class. Perhaps there is an option you need to enable in order to debug a Maps Application and prevent these non-helpful Logcat messages. Sadly the Maps API isn't one of my strong suit.

Comment: well thanks @Jean-PhilippeRoy, I hope some one could sort it out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I chose **Google Maps** API V2 instead of **Google Maps Android** API V2. After changing that the problem was gone. So this code is perfectly fine to create a full screen Google map and the question can be closed.

Thanks.